# Run each() function in order of number of parents

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to run a function once for every element which matches `.myClass` - But it needs to be run in the order of how many parents each element has.

```
$('.myClass').each(function(index){
  //my code
});
```

The only thing I can think of doing is doing another `each()` function just before that one that appends a data-sort attribute based on the `parents().length()` but surely there's a better way then that?

Comment: Is something preventing you from using `parents().length` in your current `each()` call?

Comment: No, but I need to sort the elements before that function is called. Or run the function in the order of number of parents through some other way.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi but how can it help in running the each callback in the order of number of parents

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`map` the number of parents along with the element to an Array of objects. Then sort it and iterate the result.

```
var els = $('.myClass');

var data = els.map(function(index, el){
  return {el: el, pars:$(el).parents().length};
}).toArray()
  .sort(function(a,b) {
    return a.pars - b.pars;
});

$.each(data, function(i, obj) {
    var el = obj.el;
    // do something with el
});
```

Comment: Thanks. What's the correct syntax to do jquery things with `el` at that point? `$(el)` and `el` aren't working.

Comment: @sanjaypoyzer: `el` is a DOM element, so to use jQuery methods, you pass it to the jQuery function `$(el)`. If that doesn't work, I don't know why. Did you copy/paste the code above correctly?